# Adding a table to list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I have created a table using `tabular`, however when I compile my document the table is not present in the list of tables. Do I have to manually append it to the `list of tables` as I have used tabular instead of table? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: If your table doesn't have a caption (description), why add it to the list?

Comment: You can do `\captionlistentry[table]{Description}` using package `caption`/

Comment: The list of tables actually lists *captions*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As some have mentioned in the comments, the List of Tables lists *captions*; if you don't have a caption, it won't know what to list.  In any case, it's the `\caption` command that writes an entry to the `lot` file, and that's what LaTeX inputs to form the List of Tables when you issue `\listoftables`.

If you're not using captions, you're probably not loading `caption`, which means that @Johannes_B's answer won't work for you.  What you're really looking for is `\addcontentsline`:

```
\addcontentsline{fileextension}{entrytype}{entrytext}
```

`fileextension` is whatever list you want to make an entry in; use `toc` for the table of contents, `lof` for list of figures, and `lot` for list of tables.  `entrytype` is what type of entry you're trying to make, which is usually more relevant in a the TOC than the LOT; just use `table` here.  And `entrytext` is what the list will include; since you don't have a caption, you'll have to make up something appropriate here.  An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{What is this doing?}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
What & is \\
this & doing? \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This code gets you:

[image: Table in the LOT]

Obviously, this is a terrible and useless table; but you can see that it's put into the LOT as expected.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to load the `caption` package and use `\captionof{table}{The caption}` instead of manually adding `\addcontentsline` which does neither provide a correct numbering nor a reference label.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\clearpage

\begingroup
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ll}
What & is \\
this & doing? \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{A nice table}\label{tbl:nicetablelesstable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

nest your `tabular` inside a `table` environment, and add a `caption` entry. That's it.

The syntax then is: `\caption[text that goes to LoT]{text that reads below/above the table}`

If you add it by hand as @dgoodmaniii explains, to also have a numbered entry in the LoT add a reference:

```
...
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\ref{tbL:label} What is this doing?}
...
```

of course, you need to define a `\label{tbl:label}` somewhere, preferably next to the table (or in the used environment)

Comment: You should explicitly explain how you define a `\label{tbl:label}` without using `\caption` ;-)  It is possible, of course